# Why should I precompile my Typescript project for production instead of running directly with ts-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

Everyone says that *production builds should be precompiled*.

But I don't understand why.

What problems can happen if I run project in production with `node --loader ts-node/esm src/server.ts` ?

Comment: It really depends on what you're writing. In general this is good advice but in certain cases, say tests or examples, it's not gospel.

Answer (score 0):

The main consideration is a performance consideration. The code changes every time you deploy it, not every time you start up the application, so it's wasteful to transpile it on the fly on each run.

Comment: My app has about 10k lines and it starts in 500ms. It's acceptable startup time. If there are no other downsides, then it's perfect for me.